# Input value updated with .val() not display until field clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop down that when a value is selected, there is an ajax query that updates the last input field (Taux de...).

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  cache: false,
  url: '/Product/AgentCommissionBaseRate/' + $('input[name=ProductOid]').val() + "_" + $('input[name=Insurer]').val(),
  success: function(data) {
    //attempt1
    document.getElementById('AgentCommissionBaseRate').setAttribute('value', data);
    //attempt2
    $('#AgentCommissionBaseRate').attr("value", data);
    //attempt3
    $('#AgentCommissionBaseRate').val(data);
    alert($('#AgentCommissionBaseRate').val()) < --Shows proper value
  }
});
```

If I check with an alert box, the value is properly updated. But the new value doesn't show in the input UNTIL I CLICK ON THE FIELD. Been stuggleing for a while on this!

[image: Field interation]

Comment: Are you able to add the HTML for your `select` element?

Comment: More info is needed here. Maybe an online example here: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: `#AgentCommissionBaseRate` is a `<select>` element right? It doesn't have a `.value` property but a `.selectedIndex`. I don't know how `$.val()` works on a select-element.

Comment: Is `data` a string, or is it perhaps an object *containing* a property that is a string?

Comment: @Halcyon .val() works just fine on a select - jQuery will set the relevant `<option>` (the one whose "value" attribute matches the value passed in) as the selected item. And if .val() is called to read from the `<select>`, it will find the selected option and get its value. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/h4usrpne/ (In fact, if the native DOM element is used instead to reference the select, then reading/writing `.value` on that will also have the same effect. What _wouldn't_ work (from the OP's code) is `.attr("value"...`), since `value` is a property, not an attribute.

Comment: @Halcyon having said all that, no I don't think that field is a `<select>`. It looks like a text/numeric input field, to me. But yes some relevant HTML would help to clear things up.